# TikZ: how to specify the location of a matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw two matrices side by side, and use an arrow to connect them.  Does anyone know how to specify the exact location of these two matrices?

Comment: You'd better add some sketch of your code or at least (photo) picture showing your idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `matrix` is just a special type of `node`, and the same syntax applies. You can use for example explicit coordinates, or the `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m1) at (0,0) { \node{a}; \\ \node{b}; \\};
\matrix (m2) at (4,0) { \node{c}; \\ \node{d}; \\};
\matrix (m3) [below=of m1] { \node{e}; \\ \node{f}; \\};

\draw [->] (m1) -- (m2);
\draw [->] (m1) -- (m3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]